# Azure Websites Git Deploy: npm install bower failure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-git-deployment

So this is certainly an interesting situation. Have an ASP.NET MVC4 site which is leveraging bower and gulp. I have this site hooked into GitHub and using Azure's continuous integration. This worked perfectly fine out of box until I wanted to also integrate my gulp tasks into the automated build process.

So, I went ahead and installed the Azure CLI tools through npm. I was then able to generate a custom deployment script (deploy.cmd). Through that, I was able to edit it and add some custom scripts I found through querying the best way to accomplish npm installs, bower installs and gulp tasks through Azure. In particular, here's what I added (in case you're curious):

```
:: NPM
echo Moving to source directory
pushd "source\MeMeMe.Web"

echo Installing npm packages: Starting %TIME%
call :ExecuteCmd npm install
echo Installing npm packages: Finished %TIME%
IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error

:: Bower
echo Installing bower packages: Starting %TIME%
call :ExecuteCmd "bower" install
echo Installing bower packages: Finished %TIME%
IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error

:: Gulp
echo Running Gulp: Starting %TIME%
call :ExecuteCmd "gulp"
echo Running Gulp: Finished %TIME%

echo Publishing dist folder files to temporary deployment location
call :ExecuteCmd "xcopy" "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\source\MeMeMe.Web\dist\*.*" "%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%\dist" /S /Y /I
echo Done publishing dist folder files to temporary deployment location

IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error

:: Heading back to the stock KuduSync that follows
echo Moving back from source directory
popd
```

Now, as an aside, my package.json does NOT have bower included in it. I've read rumblings out there that Azure Websites have bower installed globally...but so far this had not worked. Every time I try a deploy without bower as a package, my npm log falls over asking for it inside the .bin directory to no avail.

So to mitigate that issue I (begrudgingly) added bower as a dependency in my package.json and checked in the code.

After about 6 minutes of building on Azure, the process fails. In the npm log, we see numerous npm errors like this one:

***npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename***

And under rename is a very long path. So bower doesn't install.

Is anyone aware of any workarounds to this? Without having to install bower as a dependency and then checking in node_modules into Git, of course. I'm at a loss to alternatives.

EDIT: Here's the full log (I changed the name of my client to MeMeMe, FWIW):

```
Command: deploy.cmd
Handling .NET Web Application deployment.
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '14.0' from 'D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin'.
All packages listed in packages.config are already installed.
  MeMeMe.Core -> D:\home\site\repository\source\MeMeMe.Core\bin\Release\MeMeMe.Core.dll
  No way to resolve conflict between "System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" and "System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35". Choosing "System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" arbitrarily.
  No way to resolve conflict between "System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" and "System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35". Choosing "System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" arbitrarily.
  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Web.Mvc, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" from Version "5.0.0.0" [] to Version "5.2.3.0" [D:\home\site\repository\source\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.5.2.3\lib\net45\System.Web.Mvc.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Web.Razor, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" from Version "1.0.0.0" [d:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\Assemblies\System.Web.Razor.dll] to Version "3.0.0.0" [D:\home\site\repository\source\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.3.2.3\lib\net45\System.Web.Razor.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "Microsoft.Owin, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" from Version "2.1.0.0" [] to Version "3.0.1.0" [D:\home\site\repository\source\packages\Microsoft.Owin.3.0.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Web.Http, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" from Version "4.0.0.0" [] to Version "5.2.3.0" [D:\home\site\repository\source\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core.5.2.3\lib\net45\System.Web.Http.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "Newtonsoft.Json, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" from Version "4.5.0.0" [] to Version "6.0.0.0" [D:\home\site\repository\source\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.8\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Net.Http.Formatting, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" from Version "4.0.0.0" [] to Version "5.2.3.0" [D:\home\site\repository\source\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client.5.2.3\lib\net45\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" from Version "1.0.0.0" [d:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\Assemblies\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll] to Version "3.0.0.0" [D:\home\site\repository\source\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.2.3\lib\net45\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "Microsoft.Owin.Security, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" from Version "2.1.0.0" [] to Version "3.0.1.0" [D:\home\site\repository\source\packages\Microsoft.Owin.Security.3.0.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.Security.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Web.WebPages.Deployment, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" from Version "1.0.0.0" [d:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\Assemblies\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll] to Version "3.0.0.0" [D:\home\site\repository\source\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.2.3\lib\net45\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "MySql.Data, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" from Version "6.9.7.0" [] to Version "6.9.8.0" [D:\home\site\repository\source\packages\MySql.Data.6.9.8\lib\net45\MySql.Data.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" from Version "2.1.0.0" [] to Version "3.0.1.0" [D:\home\site\repository\source\packages\Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.3.0.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" from Version "2.1.0.0" [] to Version "3.0.1.0" [D:\home\site\repository\source\packages\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.3.0.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Web.WebPages, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" from Version "1.0.0.0" [d:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\Assemblies\System.Web.WebPages.dll] to Version "3.0.0.0" [D:\home\site\repository\source\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.2.3\lib\net45\System.Web.WebPages.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1819,5): warning MSB3247: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly. In Visual Studio, double-click this warning (or select it and press Enter) to fix the conflicts; otherwise, add the following binding redirects to the "runtime" node in the application configuration file: <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Razor" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages.Razor" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages.Deployment" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.9.8.0" newVersion="6.9.8.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding> [D:\home\site\repository\source\MeMeMe.Data\MeMeMe.Data.csproj]
  MeMeMe.Data -> D:\home\site\repository\source\MeMeMe.Data\bin\Release\MeMeMe.Data.dll
  MeMeMe.Web -> D:\home\site\repository\source\MeMeMe.Web\bin\MeMeMe.Web.dll
  Transformed Web.config using D:\home\site\repository\source\MeMeMe.Web\Web.Release.config into obj\Release\TransformWebConfig\transformed\Web.config.
  Copying all files to temporary location below for package/publish:
  D:\local\Temp\8d31a1b73c1e2d3.
Moving to source directory
Installing npm packages: Starting  0:10:45.63
npm WARN deprecated lodash@1.0.2: lodash@<2.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^3.0.0
npm WARN deprecated npmconf@2.1.2: this package has been reintegrated into npm and is now out of date with respect to npm
MeMeMe.Web@1.0.0 D:\home\site\repository\source\MeMeMe.Web
+-- del@2.2.0 
¦ +-- globby@4.0.0 
¦ ¦ +-- array-union@1.0.1 
¦ ¦ +-- arrify@1.0.1 
¦ ¦ +-- glob@6.0.4 
¦ ¦   +-- inflight@1.0.4 
¦ ¦   ¦ +-- wrappy@1.0.1 
¦ ¦   +-- once@1.3.3 
¦ ¦   +-- path-is-absolute@1.0.0 
¦ +-- is-path-cwd@1.0.0 
¦ +-- is-path-in-cwd@1.0.0 
¦ ¦ +-- is-path-inside@1.0.0 
¦ ¦   +-- path-is-inside@1.0.1 
¦ +-- object-assign@4.0.1 
¦ +-- pify@2.3.0 
¦ +-- pinkie-promise@2.0.0 
¦ ¦ +-- pinkie@2.0.1 
¦ +-- rimraf@2.5.0 
+-- gulp@3.9.0 
¦ +-- archy@1.0.0 
¦ +-- chalk@1.1.1 
¦ ¦ +-- ansi-styles@2.1.0 
¦ ¦ +-- escape-string-regexp@1.0.4 
¦ ¦ +-- has-ansi@2.0.0 
¦ ¦ ¦ +-- ansi-regex@2.0.0 
¦ ¦ +-- strip-ansi@3.0.0 
¦ ¦ +-- supports-color@2.0.0 
¦ +-- deprecated@0.0.1 
¦ +-?? interpret@0.6.6 
¦ +-- liftoff@2.2.0 
¦ ¦ +-- extend@2.0.1 
¦ ¦ +-- findup-sync@0.3.0 
¦ ¦ ¦ +-- glob@5.0.15 
¦ ¦ +-- flagged-respawn@0.3.1 
¦ ¦ +-- rechoir@0.6.2 
¦ ¦ +-- resolve@1.1.6 
¦ +-- minimist@1.2.0 
¦ +-- orchestrator@0.3.7 
¦ ¦ +-- end-of-stream@0.1.5 
¦ ¦ +-- sequencify@0.0.7 
¦ ¦ +-- stream-consume@0.1.0 
¦ +-- pretty-hrtime@1.0.1 
¦ +-- semver@4.3.6 
¦ +-- tildify@1.1.2 
¦ ¦ +-- os-homedir@1.0.1 
¦ +-- v8flags@2.0.11 
¦ ¦ +-- user-home@1.1.1 
¦ +-- vinyl-fs@0.3.14 
¦   +-- defaults@1.0.3 
¦   +-- glob-stream@3.1.18 
¦   ¦ +-- glob@4.5.3 
¦   ¦ +-- glob2base@0.0.12 
¦   ¦ ¦ +-- find-index@0.1.1 
¦   ¦ +-- minimatch@2.0.10 
¦   ¦ +-- ordered-read-streams@0.1.0 
¦   ¦ +-- through2@0.6.5 
¦   ¦ ¦ +-- readable-stream@1.0.33 
¦   ¦ ??-- unique-stream@1.0.0 
¦   +-- glob-watcher@0.0.6 
¦   +-- graceful-fs@3.0.8 
¦   +-- strip-bom@1.0.0 
¦   ¦ +-- first-chunk-stream@1.0.0 
¦   ¦ +-- is-utf8@0.2.1 
¦   +-- through2@0.6.5 
¦   ¦ +-- readable-stream@1.0.33 
¦   +-- vinyl@0.4.6 
¦     +-- clone@0.2.0 
+-- gulp-autoprefixer@3.1.0 
¦ +-- autoprefixer@6.2.3 
¦ ¦ +-- browserslist@1.0.1 
¦ ¦ +-- caniuse-db@1.0.30000385 
¦ ¦ +-- normalize-range@0.1.2 
¦ ¦ +-- num2fraction@1.2.2 
¦ ¦ +-- postcss-value-parser@3.2.3 
¦ +-- postcss@5.0.14 
¦ ¦ +-- js-base64@2.1.9 
¦ ¦ +-- source-map@0.5.3 
¦ ¦ +-- supports-color@3.1.2 
¦ +-- through2@2.0.0 
¦ ¦ +-- readable-stream@2.0.5 
¦ ¦ ¦ +-- core-util-is@1.0.2 
¦ ¦ ¦ +-- process-nextick-args@1.0.6 
¦ ¦ ¦ +-- util-deprecate@1.0.2 
¦ ¦ +-- xtend@4.0.1 
¦ +-- vinyl-sourcemaps-apply@0.2.1 
+-- gulp-concat@2.6.0 
¦ +-- concat-with-sourcemaps@1.0.4 
¦ +-- through2@0.6.5 
¦   +-- readable-stream@1.0.33 
+-- gulp-csso@1.0.1 
¦ +-- csso@1.4.4 
¦   +-- clap@1.0.10 
+-- gulp-if@2.0.0 
¦ +-- gulp-match@1.0.0 
¦ ¦ +-- minimatch@3.0.0 
¦ ¦   +-- brace-expansion@1.1.2 
¦ ¦     +-- balanced-match@0.3.0 
¦ ¦     +-- concat-map@0.0.1 
¦ +-- ternary-stream@2.0.0 
¦   +-- duplexify@3.4.2 
¦   ¦ +-- end-of-stream@1.0.0 
¦   ¦ +-- readable-stream@2.0.5 
¦   +-- fork-stream@0.0.4 
¦   +-- merge-stream@1.0.0 
¦     +-- readable-stream@2.0.5 
+-- gulp-rename@1.2.2 
+-- gulp-sass@2.1.1 
¦ +-- node-sass@3.4.2 
¦   +-- async-foreach@0.1.3 
¦   +-- cross-spawn@2.1.4 
¦   ¦ +-- cross-spawn-async@2.1.6 
¦   ¦ ¦ +-- lru-cache@4.0.0 
¦   ¦ ¦   +-- pseudomap@1.0.2 
¦   ¦ ¦   +-- yallist@2.0.0 
¦   ¦ +-- spawn-sync@1.0.15 
¦   ¦   +-- concat-stream@1.5.1 
¦   ¦   ¦ +-- readable-stream@2.0.5 
¦   ¦   ¦ +-- typedarray@0.0.6 
¦   ¦   +-- os-shim@0.1.3 
¦   +-- gaze@0.5.2 
¦   ¦ +-- globule@0.1.0 
¦   ¦   +-- glob@3.1.21 
¦   ¦   ¦ +-- graceful-fs@1.2.3 
¦   ¦   ¦ +-- inherits@1.0.2 
¦   ¦   +-- lodash@1.0.2 
¦   ¦   +-- minimatch@0.2.14 
¦   +-- get-stdin@4.0.1 
¦   +-- glob@5.0.15 
¦   +-- meow@3.7.0 
¦   ¦ +-- camelcase-keys@2.0.0 
¦   ¦ ¦ +-- camelcase@2.0.1 
¦   ¦ +-- decamelize@1.1.2 
¦   ¦ +-- loud-rejection@1.2.0 
¦   ¦ ¦ +-- signal-exit@2.1.2 
¦   ¦ +-- map-obj@1.0.1 
¦   ¦ +-- normalize-package-data@2.3.5 
¦   ¦ ¦ +-- hosted-git-info@2.1.4 
¦   ¦ ¦ +-- is-builtin-module@1.0.0 
¦   ¦ ¦ ¦ +-- builtin-modules@1.1.1 
¦   ¦ ¦ +-- validate-npm-package-license@3.0.1 
¦   ¦ ¦   +-- spdx-correct@1.0.2 
¦   ¦ ¦   ¦ +-- spdx-license-ids@1.1.0 
¦   ¦ ¦   +-- spdx-expression-parse@1.0.2 
¦   ¦ ¦     +-- spdx-exceptions@1.0.4 
¦   ¦ +-- read-pkg-up@1.0.1 
¦   ¦ ¦ +-- find-up@1.1.0 
¦   ¦ ¦ ¦ +-- path-exists@2.1.0 
¦   ¦ ¦ +-- read-pkg@1.1.0 
¦   ¦ ¦   +-- load-json-file@1.1.0 
¦   ¦ ¦   ¦ +-- parse-json@2.2.0 
¦   ¦ ¦   ¦ ¦ +-- error-ex@1.3.0 
¦   ¦ ¦   ¦ ¦   +-- is-arrayish@0.2.1 
¦   ¦ ¦   ¦ +-- strip-bom@2.0.0 
¦   ¦ ¦   +-- path-type@1.1.0 
¦   ¦ +-- redent@1.0.0 
¦   ¦ ¦ +-- indent-string@2.1.0 
¦   ¦ ¦ ¦ +-- repeating@2.0.0 
¦   ¦ ¦ ¦   +-- is-finite@1.0.1 
¦   ¦ ¦ +-- strip-indent@1.0.1 
¦   ¦ +-- trim-newlines@1.0.0 
¦   +-- nan@2.2.0 
¦   +-- node-gyp@3.2.1 
¦   ¦ +-- fstream@1.0.8 
¦   ¦ +-- glob@4.5.3 
¦   ¦ ¦ +-- minimatch@2.0.10 
¦   ¦ +-- minimatch@1.0.0 
¦   ¦ ¦ +-- lru-cache@2.7.3 
¦   ¦ ¦ +-- sigmund@1.0.1 
¦   ¦ +-- nopt@3.0.6 
¦   ¦ ¦ +-- abbrev@1.0.7 
¦   ¦ +-- npmlog@1.2.1 
¦   ¦ ¦ +-- ansi@0.3.0 
¦   ¦ ¦ +-- are-we-there-yet@1.0.5 
¦   ¦ ¦ ¦ +-- delegates@0.1.0 
¦   ¦ ¦ +-- gauge@1.2.2 
¦   ¦ ¦   +-- has-unicode@1.0.1 
¦   ¦ ¦   +-- lodash.pad@3.1.1 
¦   ¦ ¦   ¦ +-- lodash._createpadding@3.6.1 
¦   ¦ ¦   ¦   +-- lodash.repeat@3.0.1 
¦   ¦ ¦   +-- lodash.padleft@3.1.1 
¦   ¦ ¦   +-- lodash.padright@3.1.1 
¦   ¦ +-- osenv@0.1.3 
¦   ¦ ¦ +-- os-tmpdir@1.0.1 
¦   ¦ +-- path-array@1.0.0 
¦   ¦ ¦ +-- array-index@0.1.1 
¦   ¦ ¦   +-- debug@2.2.0 
¦   ?? ¦     +-- ms@0.7.1 
¦   ¦ +-- tar@2.2.1 
¦   ¦ ¦ +-- block-stream@0.0.8 
¦   ¦ +-- which@1.2.1 
¦   ¦   +-- is-absolute@0.1.7 
¦   ¦     +-- is-relative@0.1.3 
¦   +-- npmconf@2.1.2 
¦   ¦ +-- config-chain@1.1.9 
¦   ¦ ¦ +-- proto-list@1.2.4 
¦   ¦ +-- ini@1.3.4 
¦   ¦ +-- uid-number@0.0.5 
¦   +-- request@2.67.0 
¦   ¦ +-- aws-sign2@0.6.0 
¦   ¦ +-- bl@1.0.0 
¦   ¦ ¦ +-- readable-stream@2.0.5 
¦   ¦ +-- caseless@0.11.0 
¦   ¦ +-- combined-stream@1.0.5 
¦   ¦ ¦ +-- delayed-stream@1.0.0 
¦   ¦ +-- extend@3.0.0 
¦   ¦ +-- forever-agent@0.6.1 
¦   ¦ +-- form-data@1.0.0-rc3 
¦   ¦ +-- har-validator@2.0.3 
¦   ¦ ¦ +-- commander@2.9.0 
¦   ¦ ¦ ¦ +-- graceful-readlink@1.0.1 
¦   ¦ ¦ +-- is-my-json-valid@2.12.3 
¦   ¦ ¦   +-- generate-function@2.0.0 
¦   ¦ ¦   +-- generate-object-property@1.2.0 
¦   ¦ ¦   ¦ +-- is-property@1.0.2 
¦   ¦ ¦   +-- jsonpointer@2.0.0 
¦   ¦ +-- hawk@3.1.2 
¦   ¦ ¦ +-- boom@2.10.1 
¦   ¦ ¦ +-- cryptiles@2.0.5 
¦   ¦ ¦ +-- hoek@2.16.3 
¦   ¦ ¦ +-- sntp@1.0.9 
¦   ¦ +-- http-signature@1.1.0 
¦   ¦ ¦ +-- assert-plus@0.1.5 
¦   ¦ ¦ +-- jsprim@1.2.2 
¦   ¦ ¦ ¦ +-- extsprintf@1.0.2 
¦   ¦ ¦ ¦ +-- json-schema@0.2.2 
¦   ¦ ¦ ¦ +-- verror@1.3.6 
¦   ¦ ¦ +-- sshpk@1.7.2 
¦   ¦ ¦   +-- asn1@0.2.3 
¦   ¦ ¦   +-- assert-plus@0.2.0 
¦   ¦ ¦   +-- dashdash@1.12.1 
¦   ¦ ¦   +-- ecc-jsbn@0.1.1 
¦   ¦ ¦   +-- jodid25519@1.0.2 
¦   ¦ ¦   +-- jsbn@0.1.0 
¦   ¦ ¦   +-- tweetnacl@0.13.3 
¦   ¦ +-- is-typedarray@1.0.0 
¦   ¦ +-- isstream@0.1.2 
¦   ¦ +-- json-stringify-safe@5.0.1 
¦   ¦ +-- mime-types@2.1.9 
¦   ¦ ¦ +-- mime-db@1.21.0 
¦   ¦ +-- node-uuid@1.4.7 
¦   ¦ +-- oauth-sign@0.8.0 
¦   ¦ +-- qs@5.2.0 
¦   ¦ +-- stringstream@0.0.5 
¦   ¦ +-- tough-cookie@2.2.1 
¦   ¦ +-- tunnel-agent@0.4.2 
¦   +-- sass-graph@2.0.1 
¦     +-- glob@5.0.15 
¦     +-- lodash@3.10.1 
¦     +-- yargs@3.31.0 
¦       +-- cliui@3.1.0 
¦       ¦ +-- wrap-ansi@1.0.0 
¦       +-- os-locale@1.4.0 
¦       ¦ +-- lcid@1.0.0 
¦       ¦   +-- invert-kv@1.0.0 
¦       +-- string-width@1.0.1 
¦       ¦ +-- code-point-at@1.0.0 
¦       ¦ ¦ +-- number-is-nan@1.0.0 
¦       ¦ +-- is-fullwidth-code-point@1.0.0 
¦       +-- window-size@0.1.4 
¦       +-- y18n@3.2.0 
+-- gulp-uglify@1.5.1 
¦ +-- deap@1.0.0 
¦ +-- fancy-log@1.1.0 
¦ +-- isobject@2.0.0 
¦ ¦ +-- isarray@0.0.1 
¦ +-- uglify-js@2.6.0 
¦ ¦ +-- async@0.2.10 
¦ ¦ +-- uglify-to-browserify@1.0.2 
¦ ¦ +-- yargs@3.10.0 
¦ ¦   +-- camelcase@1.2.1 
¦ ¦   +-- cliui@2.1.0 
¦ ¦   ¦ +-- center-align@0.1.2 
¦ ¦   ¦ ¦ +-- align-text@0.1.3 
¦ ¦   ¦ ¦ ¦ +-- kind-of@2.0.1 
¦ ¦   ¦ ¦ ¦ +-- longest@1.0.1 
¦ ¦   ¦ ¦ ¦ +-- repeat-string@1.5.2 
¦ ¦   ¦ ¦ +-- lazy-cache@0.2.7 
¦ ¦   ¦ +-- right-align@0.1.3 
¦ ¦   +-- window-size@0.1.0 
¦ +-- uglify-save-license@0.4.1 
+-- gulp-util@3.0.7 
¦ +-- array-differ@1.0.0 
¦ +-- array-uniq@1.0.2 
¦ +-- beeper@1.1.0 
¦ +-- dateformat@1.0.12 
¦ +-- gulplog@1.0.0 
¦ ¦ +-- glogg@1.0.0 
¦ +-- has-gulplog@0.1.0 
¦ ¦ +-- sparkles@1.0.0 
¦ +-- lodash._reescape@3.0.0 
¦ +-- lodash._reevaluate@3.0.0 
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
¦ +-- lodash._reinterpolate@3.0.0 
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.6
¦ +-- lodash.template@3.6.2 
npm WARN MeMeMe.Web@1.0.0 No description
¦ ¦ +-- lodash._basecopy@3.0.1 
npm WARN MeMeMe.Web@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.2.9200
¦ ¦ +-- lodash._basetostring@3.0.1 
npm ERR! argv "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\4.2.3\\node.exe" "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\npm\\3.5.1\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
¦ ¦ +-- lodash._basevalues@3.0.0 
npm ERR! node v4.2.3
¦ ¦ +-- lodash._isiterateecall@3.0.9 
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.1
¦ ¦ +-- lodash.escape@3.0.0 
npm ERR! path D:\home\site\repository\source\MeMeMe.Web\node_modules\.staging\capture-stack-trace-59075fa10eb642e1b47ea9ed18a76ec3
¦ ¦ +-- lodash.keys@3.1.2 
npm ERR! code ENOENT
¦ ¦ ¦ +-- lodash._getnative@3.9.1 
npm ERR! errno -4058
¦ ¦ ¦ +-- lodash.isarguments@3.0.4 
npm ERR! syscall rename
¦ ¦ ¦ +-- lodash.isarray@3.0.4 

¦ ¦ +-- lodash.restparam@3.6.1 
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'D:\home\site\repository\source\MeMeMe.Web\node_modules\.staging\capture-stack-trace-59075fa10eb642e1b47ea9ed18a76ec3' -> 'D:\home\site\repository\source\MeMeMe.Web\node_modules\bower\node_modules\update-notifier\node_modules\latest-version\node_modules\package-json\node_modules\got\node_modules\create-error-class\node_modules\capture-stack-trace'
¦ ¦ +-- lodash.templatesettings@3.1.0 
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'D:\home\site\repository\source\MeMeMe.Web\node_modules\.staging\capture-stack-trace-59075fa10eb642e1b47ea9ed18a76ec3' -> 'D:\home\site\repository\source\MeMeMe.Web\node_modules\bower\node_modules\update-notifier\node_modules\latest-version\node_modules\package-json\node_modules\got\node_modules\create-error-class\node_modules\capture-stack-trace'
¦ +-- multipipe@0.1.2 
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
¦ ¦ +-- duplexer2@0.0.2 
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
¦ +-- object-assign@3.0.0 
npm ERR! enoent 
¦ +-- replace-ext@0.0.1 

¦ +-- vinyl@0.5.3 
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
¦   +-- clone-stats@0.0.1 
npm ERR!     D:\home\site\repository\source\MeMeMe.Web\npm-debug.log
+-- gutil@1.6.4 
¦ +-- sliced@1.0.1 
+-- path@0.12.7 
¦ +-- process@0.11.2 
¦ +-- util@0.10.3 
¦   +-- inherits@2.0.1 
+-- rename@1.0.3 
¦ +-- debug@2.1.3 
¦   +-- ms@0.7.0 
+-- run-sequence@1.1.5 
+??- semver-utils@1.1.1  extraneous
+-- webpack@1.12.10 
  +-- async@1.5.2 
  +-- clone@1.0.2 
  +-- enhanced-resolve@0.9.1 
  ¦ +-- graceful-fs@4.1.2 
  ¦ +-- memory-fs@0.2.0 
  +-- esprima@2.7.1 
  +-- loader-utils@0.2.12 
  ¦ +-- big.js@3.1.3 
  ¦ +-- json5@0.4.0 
  +-- memory-fs@0.3.0 
  ¦ +-- errno@0.1.4 
  ¦ ¦ +-- prr@0.0.0 
  ¦ +-- readable-stream@2.0.5 
  +-- mkdirp@0.5.1 
  ¦ +-- minimist@0.0.8 
  +-- node-libs-browser@0.5.3 
  ¦ +-- assert@1.3.0 
  ¦ +-- browserify-zlib@0.1.4 
  ¦ ¦ +-- pako@0.2.8 
  ¦ +-- buffer@3.6.0 
  ¦ ¦ +-- base64-js@0.0.8 
  ¦ ¦ +-- ieee754@1.1.6 
  ¦ ¦ +-- isarray@1.0.0 
  ¦ +-- console-browserify@1.1.0 
  ¦ ¦ +-- date-now@0.1.4 
  ¦ +-- constants-browserify@0.0.1 
  ¦ +-- crypto-browserify@3.2.8 
  ¦ ¦ +-- pbkdf2-compat@2.0.1 
  ¦ ¦ +-- ripemd160@0.2.0 
  ¦ ¦ +-- sha.js@2.2.6 
  ¦ +-- domain-browser@1.1.7 
  ¦ +-- events@1.1.0 
  ¦ +-- http-browserify@1.7.0 
  ¦ ¦ +-- Base64@0.2.1 
  ¦ +-- https-browserify@0.0.0 
  ¦ +-- os-browserify@0.1.2 
  ¦ +-- path-browserify@0.0.0 
  ¦ +-- punycode@1.4.0 
  ¦ +-- querystring-es3@0.2.1 
  ¦ +-- readable-stream@1.1.13 
  ¦ +-- stream-browserify@1.0.0 
  ¦ +-- string_decoder@0.10.31 
  ¦ +-- timers-browserify@1.4.2 
  ¦ +-- tty-browserify@0.0.0 
  ¦ +-- url@0.10.3 
  ¦ ¦ +-- punycode@1.3.2 
  ¦ ¦ +-- querystring@0.2.0 
  ¦ +-- vm-browserify@0.0.4 
  ¦   +-- indexof@0.0.1 
  +-- optimist@0.6.1 
  ¦ +-- minimist@0.0.10 
  ¦ +-- wordwrap@0.0.2 
  +-- supports-color@3.1.2 
  ¦ +-- has-flag@1.0.0 
  +-- tapable@0.1.10 
  +-- watchpack@0.2.9 
  ¦ +-- async@0.9.2 
  ¦ +-- chokidar@1.4.2 
  ¦   +-- anymatch@1.3.0 
  ¦   ¦ +-- micromatch@2.3.7 
  ¦   ¦   +-- arr-diff@2.0.0 
  ¦   ¦   ¦ +-- arr-flatten@1.0.1 
  ¦   ¦   +-- array-unique@0.2.1 
  ¦   ¦   +-- braces@1.8.3 
  ¦   ¦   ¦ +-- expand-range@1.8.1 
  ¦   ¦   ¦ ¦ +-- fill-range@2.2.3 
  ¦   ¦   ¦ ¦   +-- is-number@2.1.0 
  ¦   ¦   ¦ ¦   ¦ +-- kind-of@3.0.2 
  ¦   ¦   ¦ ¦   +-- randomatic@1.1.5 
  ¦   ¦   ¦ ¦     +-- kind-of@3.0.2 
  ¦   ¦   ¦ +-- preserve@0.2.0 
  ¦   ¦   ¦ +-- repeat-element@1.1.2 
  ¦   ¦   +-- expand-brackets@0.1.4 
  ¦   ¦   +-- extglob@0.3.1 
  ¦   ¦   ¦ +-- ansi-green@0.1.1 
  ¦   ¦   ¦ ¦ +-- ansi-wrap@0.1.0 
  ¦   ¦   ¦ +-- success-symbol@0.1.0 
  ¦   ¦   +-- filename-regex@2.0.0 
  ¦   ¦   +-- kind-of@3.0.2 
  ¦   ¦   ¦ +-- is-buffer@1.1.1 
  ¦   ¦   +??- normalize-path@2.0.1 
  ¦   ¦   +-- object.omit@2.0.0 
  ¦   ¦   ¦ +-- for-own@0.1.3 
  ¦   ¦   ¦ ¦ +-- for-in@0.1.4 
  ¦   ¦   ¦ +-- is-extendable@0.1.1 
  ¦   ¦   +-- parse-glob@3.0.4 
  ¦   ¦   ¦ +-- glob-base@0.3.0 
  ¦   ¦   ¦ +-- is-dotfile@1.0.2 
  ¦   ¦   +-- regex-cache@0.4.2 
  ¦   ¦     +-- is-equal-shallow@0.1.3 
  ¦   ¦     +-- is-primitive@2.0.0 
  ¦   +-- async-each@0.1.6 
  ¦   +-- glob-parent@2.0.0 
  ¦   +-- is-binary-path@1.0.1 
  ¦   ¦ +-- binary-extensions@1.4.0 
  ¦   +-- is-glob@2.0.1 
  ¦   ¦ +-- is-extglob@1.0.0 
  ¦   +-- readdirp@2.0.0 
  ¦     +-- minimatch@2.0.10 
  ¦     +-- readable-stream@2.0.5 
  +-- webpack-core@0.6.8 
    +-- source-list-map@0.1.5 
    +-- source-map@0.4.4 
      +-- amdefine@1.0.0 

Failed exitCode=-4058, command=npm install
Installing npm packages: Finished  0:18:35.21
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
```

Comment: can you past the full deployment log? also if you go to your scm site `https://{your site name}.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole` and navigate to `D:\home\LogFiles\kudu\trace`, check log that contains `Deploy` keyword, to see if there is any extra errors.

Comment: Hi @XiaominWu I added the log. Thanks.

Comment: BTW, when locally i assume the app is running fine for you? what version of node do you use locally?

Comment: Correct. Does work fine. NPM is 2.5.1. Node is 0.12.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my guess is you might hitting file path max length limit.

```
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'D:\home\site\repository\source\MeMeMe.Web\node_modules\.staging\capture-stack-trace-59075fa10eb642e1b47ea9ed18a76ec3' -> 'D:\home\site\repository\source\MeMeMe.Web\node_modules\bower\node_modules\update-notifier\node_modules\latest-version\node_modules\package-json\node_modules\got\node_modules\create-error-class\node_modules\capture-stack-trace'
```

from above log, can you check if there is any file path under `D:\home\site\repository\source\MeMeMe.Web\node_modules\.staging\capture-stack-trace-59075fa10eb642e1b47ea9ed18a76ec3` is more than 256 characters long?

Comment: I'll try another build and see. That .staging directory is temporary so I'll monitor it. The build does take about 5-6 minutes, so I'll have plenty of time. If we're hitting a max length limit...any recommendations to get around this?

Comment: @StephenPAdams from what i learn, NPM 3 suppose to flatten all the dependency. if you can confirm that you are hitting the file length limit, try to upgrade to use npm3 which you will have to user a newer version of nodejs i think. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/nodejs-specify-node-version-azure-apps/#versioning-websites-with-app-settings